# MS GRAPH API with Azure Event hubs?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-eventhub

I have a question around Azure Event Hubs. Can you use MS Graph API to fetch relevant data from existing Azure event hubs. ( for reporting purposes, to create custom dashboards)

I have few Event hubs created (for Device, Cloudapp Events.. etc.) I want to know weather I can use MS Graph API to fetch specific Device related or CLoudapp related feed from these created events hubs. In short rather run direct MS Graph query on a tenant level, instead I want to use these Event hubs as a data source to query data.

Would this work or would Event Hubs support MS GRAPH queries?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Graph API does not provide support for Azure Event Hub and therefore cannot be used to directly fetch data from Azure Event Hubs. The Microsoft Graph API is a RESTful API that provides access to data in Microsoft 365 services, such as Azure Active Directory, Exchange Online, SharePoint, OneDrive, and Microsoft Teams. It does not have direct integration with Azure Event Hubs. However, you can use the Azure Event Hubs REST API to fetch data from the event hubs. Here is documentation to get you started.

-->Azure Event Hubs REST API documentation: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/)